# Rectifier circuit grounding

Tags: grounding, rectifier

I built a rectifier circuit, but when I attempt to measure the voltage, I only get a reading if my fingers are holding the meter leads to the rectifier leads. Am I not properly grounding the circuit unless I am touching it? If so, how do I ground it? Right now, I have my 'ground' connected back to the exterior of the coax that I am using to feed the RF signal into the rectifier circuit.

Comment: Please feel free to include a schematic diagram. The question editor has a Circuit Lab tool. A picture of the construction would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By touching both meter leads, you're adding an extra resistor to the circuit (yourself), that wasn't there before.  That would change the reading you see.

Voltmeters don't need to be "grounded" at all.  But they have 2 leads and will measure the voltage between the two points you test.  Whether or not you choose to give the name "ground" to the place you connect the negative lead to is up to you.